# Check if ports are allowed in Firewall ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, docker

Currently I'm trying to setup my ssl in docker instance. I'm trying to check if these ports are allowed in my firewall

`Port: 443 and 4021`

I've searched that allowing specific port for firewall using this terminal command

`sudo ufw allow 4021`

But how can I check and see all the ports allowed in my firewall?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is `ufw status`

Answer (score 1):

If you configure all your firewall setting with ufw, then `ufw status` would show you the ports. But sometimes (in my experience) this doesn't show all configured firewall ports and options.

You would get a general output with:
`iptables -L -v -n`

```
-L = list all ports
-v = make the output verbose
-n = do print port numbers instead of servicenames (otherwise it would print "http" or "ssh" instead of "80" or "22".

The command is faster when using the -n option an also can be `grep`ped or `ack`ed (https://beyondgrep.com/) for the port number
```

Comment: something like `sudo ufw -L?` but this gives list of commands such as `enable, disabled, default arg and so on`

Comment: what do you mean? like @itsahobby and I said: `ufw status` (use with sudo or with the root-account). Did you try it? it also "lists" the ports: `sudo ufw status`

Comment: @RaeIan is it still unclear or is your question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ufw status
```

will show allowed ports only is firewall is runing

```
sudo ufw enable
```